MismatchedInputException while deserializing XML lists with Jackson
I'm having an issue deserializing some XMl containing a list of objects.
To reproduce it, I first serialize a given object to XML, then try to deserialize the result, but it fails.
Here is my sample code:
fun main() {
    val test = CategoriesResponse(listOf(Category(1), Category(2)))
    val xmlMapper = XmlMapper()
    val xml: String = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(test)
    println(xml)
    val testObject = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, CategoriesResponse::class.java)
    println(testObject)

}


@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
data class CategoriesResponse
@JsonCreator
constructor(
    @field:JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "categories")
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "category")
    val categoryList: List<Category>
)

data class Category
@JsonCreator
constructor(
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val id: Int,
)

The produced XML is just right (formatted here):
<response>
   <categories>
      <category id="1"/>
      <category id="2"/>
   </categories>
</response> 

I'm using
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml") 
And here is the exception I get:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<Category>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.FIELD_NAME`)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I have no experience wth Jackson, but is it normal that you need a @JsonCreator annotation when you are serializing to XML? Also, the error message is about a JsonToken.FIELD_NAME which shouldn't even be relevant for XML deserialization, in my understanding.

Are you sure you that JacksonXmlProperty is the right one to use for child elements?

Something wrong with the constructor. I don't think @JsonCreator is suitable for XML. Consider adding default values so the parser will instantiate the objects by triggering their empty constructors.
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
data class CategoriesResponse(
    @field:JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "categories")
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "category")
    val categoryList: List<Category> = listOf()
)

data class Category(
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val id: Int = -1
)


It's a little bit sad, but it does work! Thank a lot
